# Is there a way to insert javascript from a external php file to the main page?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postback

I have a simple question, with maybe a difficult solution.
I hope someone can help me out.

The code is a postback file, which means that the file will execute when an action is completed on another website.
This is the code that I can edit:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE thescore SET score=score+".$_GET['new'] ." WHERE user_id =' " . $_GET['uid']. " ' "); 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO postbacks (page,ip,user_id) VALUES ('".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]."','".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."','".$_GET['uid']."')");
```

I want to add a simple alert javascript action on the main website, when the file is actived by the other site.

I hope you can help me!
Kind regards,

Maarten

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you could add the following to the file to create the alert after the query;

```
echo "<script language='javascript'>\n";
echo "  alert('Some message!');";
echo "</script>\n";
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Yes I thought so either, but the query would not display on the page, but on the external php file right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the details concerning how the file is called by the other website, but if it is something like ajax or curl, as examples, then your script won't be able to display an alert or message like you want. The other website would need to have code to accept a response and then display the alert with whatever text was sent back. In most cases like this, the other site needs to be where the alert resides--though I suppose the site could be coded to execute whatever was passed back to it, but I wouldn't recommend that (security).